# PHP - Special characters

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to send these characters through PHP:

```
áéíóúüchlñÁÉÍÓÚÜCLÑ
```

They show up in the received email like this:

> Ã¡Ã©ÃÃ³ÃºÃ¼chlÃ±ÃÃÃÃÃ

I tried htmlentities but without success:

```
$newsubject = htmlentities($subject, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
mail($notes,$newsubject,$message,$headers);
```

Does anybody have an idea what I could try?
Thanks

Comment: did you add HTML headers to the e-mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to send them as UTF-8 but your PHP is handling them as latin-1.

Call `utf8_encode` on the input string to treat it as UTF-8 again.

**EDIT:** Misread the question. Add a header to the email you're sending:
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to use MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions).

Add your mail headers the following:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your character set is wrong on the characters themselves. Try this: (Windows) Copy and paste those characters from a "UTF-8 character set" site back into your application. Make sure your doucument is UTF-8, and BOM Signature disabled.